# how can i change direction of bootstrap submenu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can i change direction of sub menu in bootstrap ? for example when i hover on menu the sub menu open in left 
something like this http://postimg.org/image/6pq4z98kn/ 
the default menu in bootstrap is this http://postimg.org/image/lxjentpmz/

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="blog-list.html">Blog</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="blog-list.html">Blog list</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-single.html">Blog single</a></li>
    </ul
</li>
```

in this theme http://envato.megadrupal.com/html/megacourse/

Comment: Post your current code hadadi

Comment: by default show the submenu dropdown in bootstrap if have the space from the left show in normal mode such as [link](http://postimg.org/image/lxjentpmz/)  if not have enough space in left hand show the submenu as this link [link](http://postimg.org/image/6pq4z98kn/)

Comment: I want to always be in left

Comment: show your <nav> code using jsfiddle....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change direction of parent to rtl and all then order the result